How to detect if headphones are plugged in for a shell script?
I'm writing my own custom status for i3/Sway that shows a volume indicator, and I've run into a snag.
I'd like to know if there is a standard way, using standard Linux tools--maybe ALSA or sysfs--to detect if headphones are plugged in, or not? I'd prefer to do it this way in case I ever want to switch from Pipewire to regular JACK at any point, or whatever.
I'll post a segment from this "half-working" solution I was able to find Online (sorry, but I can't recall who posted this so I can credit that person).

has_headset() {
    grep -A4 -ri "Headphone Playback Switch" /proc/asound/card*/* |
        grep "Amp-Out vals.*\[0x00\]*"
}


This function has_headset() sort of works, but the problem is that if the headphones are plugged in AND muted, then it won't work. Not sure what the values of "Amp-Out vals" means. Seems to be [0x80] [0x80] when the headphones are unplugged, and then [0x00] [0x00] when the headphones are plugged in and not muted.
I'm using POSIX sh, but solutions written specifically for Bash are more than welcome as well!

The answer How to check if headphones/speakers are plugged in from Roberto Polli looks to be the source of the "half-working" solution.

has_headphone() {
  for card in /proc/asound/card*; do
    amixer -c"${card##*card}" cget 'iface=CARD,name=Headphone Jack'
  done 2> /dev/null | grep -qw values=on
}

Works for me with alsa-utils 1.2.12 on Debian trixie (testing) and Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04).
See also amixer -c0 contents to see all the controls of card 0 in case the name is different from Headphone Jack in your case.
The laptop I test it on has a combined headphone + microphone TRRS jack socket but I still do see an additional Mic Jack control which switches to on when I plug a headset but not a headphone without microphone (TRS jack plug), so for a has_headset that checks whether both a headphone and microphone are connected to the same card, you could do:
jack_connected() {
  amixer -c"$1" cget "iface=CARD,name=$2 Jack" 2> /dev/null |
    grep -qw values=on
}

has_headset() {
  for card in /proc/asound/card*; do
    card=${card##*card}
    jack_connected "$card" Headphone &&
      jack_connected "$card" Mic &&
      return
  done
  false
}

Note that under strace, I see amixer doing a:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/snd/controlC0", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[...]
ioctl(3, SNDRV_CTL_IOCTL_ELEM_INFO, 0x7ffc2fdc3020) = 0

So not getting the information from /proc nor /sys.

Oh yeah, on my laptop (Framework 13 AMD), ALSA likes to set the default sound card0 to the HDMI outputs for some reason, and card1 has the rest from the Realtek ALC295. But anyway, that doesn't matter since that loop checks all cards!
Works beautifully for me. Thanks a lot!
